# Rewriting URL with selected query string parameters in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I recently changed my CMS, and want to rewrite some of my URLs to match the new URL/query string parameter format.

The old URL was:

```
http://www.mysite.com/search.cgi?tag=foo&blog_id=bar&other=baz
```

The new URL should be:

```
http://www.mysite.com/?s=foo
```

In other words, there were several query string parameters in the old format, but I only care to rewrite the **tag** param to **s** while keeping the same value.  The other parameters should be discarded.  Of course the order of the parameters shouldn't matter.  It also shouldn't matter whether tag is the only parameter or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try to use regular expression and grouping, if your server supports that. If I am not mistaken you have to rewrite only one parameter, I guess you could try something like (if you are using apache with mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\btag\b=(\w+|&\w+;)+)
RewriteRule ^(.+) /$1?%1 [L]
```

**Edit:** I improved the regular expression a little bit to match "tag" regardless of its position in the query string and to preserve special characters sequences such as `&amp;` In addition it should avoid matches with similar parameters (i.e.: it wouldn't match a parameter called "alttag").

**Edit #2:** An alternative (especially if you have to filter several parameters) is to use an external program to do the rewrite. This page: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap (in particular the section "External rewriting program") contains useful information.

Comment: So the %1 in RewriteRule reflects the regular expression match in RewriteCond?

Comment: Yes, %1 is used to refer to a group in a RewriteCond, while $1 is used to refer to a group in a RewriteRule directive.

Comment: And how would I set up my RewriteUrl specifically to map the /search.cgi?... part to /?...

Comment: Also, if I wanted this configured as a Redirect instead of a Rewrite, what would change?

Comment: To make a Redirect put R=<HTTP Status Code> after the [L]ast rule: i.e.: `RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [L,R=302]`. You can find a complete list of HTTP status codes here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html (you will have to use ones from the 300-307 range). It is common practice to use either 301 or 302 status codes.

Comment: About search.cgi: I would suggest to not use the 'root' (/) but strip the .cgi extension instead. Something like: `RewriteRule ^/search /search.cgi [L,QSA]` should do the trick. It would rewrite queries like /search?foo=bar&baz=foobar to /search.cgi?foo=bar&baz=foobar

Comment: The &amp; is an html entity not a url-encoding, so I don't think this is needed.

Answer (score 2):

On an Apache webserver, placing the following rule into .htaccess in your document root will rewrite URLs as you described:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*\btag=([^&]*).*
RewriteRule ^search\.cgi /?s=%1 [R=302]
```

The rule above uses a 302 redirect, so your browser doesn't "memorize" the redirect rule while you're testing and tweaking the rule.  Once you're done testing, change the [R] to [R=301].  A 301 is a permanent redirect, and is better for SEO.

Comment: This should redirect with `s` parameter, and it will work as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version to get specifically what the OP meant. @smhmic's answer is close to this. I just prefer explicit beginning-or-ampersand to find the parameter, rather than the word-boundary approach. (The accepted answer is overly complicated, and has some issues.)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)tag=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^search\.cgi$ /?s=%1 [NC,R=302]
```

This is saying:
`(?:   )` don't capture this as a % number
`^|&` at beginning of querystring or after an ampersand (this acts like the word boundary, but specifically for urls).
`tag=` the param we're looking for.
`(   )` capture this, into %1.
`[^&]*` zero or more characters not an ampersand (and stopping at ampersand or running to the end).

Comment: This is _almost_ exactly my solution, but the the regex is more precise. +1