# Rewrite url to remove gclid query

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, iis-6

I am trying to remove google's gclid tracking parameter from my urls. After searching around the internet it appears that I need to use url rewriting to solve the problem.

I am using IIS6 as a server so rather than .htaccess I am using isapi rewrite filter which is supposed to work the same way.

Ideally I would like to make this:

```
http://www.example.com/default.asp?parameter=stufftokeep&gclid=alotofrandomstuff
```

Become this:

```
http://www.example.com/default.asp?parameter=stufftokeep
```

no matter what comes after "gclid"

I was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111182/rewriting-url-with-selected-query-string-parameters-in-htaccess) here on SO but replacing "tag" with "gclid" did not work, and keeps breaking the page.

Has anyone run into this issue with gclid parameter before who might be able to offer a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue with gclid parameter on IIS6 server using isapi rewrite filter v2 here is the code that solved the issue.

```
RewriteRule ^/([^?]+)\?(.*)(?:^|&)gclid\=[^&]+(\&.*)?$ /$1\?$2$3 [I,RP,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(?:^|&)gclid=[^&]+(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it then added &gclid=test and got a 404 error or a broken page... I tried removing everything else from my .ini file but no luck

Comment: @HelloWorld are the rules in an htaccess file in your document root?

Comment: the rules are in a .ini file in document root using isapi rewrite filter on IIS server. I was able to solve the issue.